# How can I test this property of the nullspace subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to test the following Nullspace property: $$ Null(A) \subset Null(BA) $$
where $$ Null(A)  = {x\in \mathbb{R}^n/ A x=0} $$
$$ Null(BA)  = {y\in \mathbb{R}^n/ BA y=0} $$
For any matrix $A$,$B$ such that they have the correct dimensions to make the product.
The problem is that when I write the linear combination of the vectors $y$, to show that every vector x can be written as a linear combination of the vectors $y$, the vector $x$ that I am looking for does not appear, therefore I cannot prove that all $x$ can be written from the vectors $y$.
How can I test this property? any ideas?
Refering to the dimension of each nullspace, are they the same? that is, the symbol would be $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$?
thanks!

Comment: I think that you might have your definitions turned around. Null(BA) should be the set of y such that BAy = 0. Well, if x is in Null(A) then Ax = 0, so BAx = 0, and thus x is in Null(BA)

Comment: And the dimensions do not need to be the same. Just let A be the identity matrix and let B be a singular matrix. The null space of the identity is just the zero vector, and the dimension of the null space of a singular matrix is at least 1

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already edited the error I had in the question. Just one more question: if I multiply by $B$ on the 2 sides, I have that $B.(A.x)=0$, how can I ensure that $B.(A.x)=0$ is the same as for $(B.A).x=0$, which ensures that $x$ belongs to the $Nulll (B.A)$ for any matrix $A,B$?

Comment: No problem! Since matrices are just representations of linear transformations, and matrix multiplication is meant to correspond to composition of those transformations, we know that matrix multiplication must be associative (since composition of linear transformations is). You can also check this explicitly with some small matrices. Just take some (maybe non-square) matrices and multiply things out explicitly. This would actually be a good exercise if you have not proved it before